# How can I remove unfilled fields from a query and set it to a new object with only the fields I want?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am retrieving particular columns from an Entity Framework object based on user input.

I am able to query my database using a linq query only selecting columns that I am keeping track of using a string array, which has strings that match the fields of the object I am querying. So far I can only retrieve a "Car" object that also obviously has the rest of its fields set to null. I want to return an object that only has the fields that I am searching on, no null fields. How can I return a new object that is set to include just the fields I want?

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Query(string[] columns)
{
   return context.Cars.Select(SelectorFunction<Car>(columns);
}

public static Func<T, T> SelectorFunction<T>(string[] columns)
        {
            // input parameter "o"
            var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");

            // new statement "new Data()"
            var xNew = Expression.New(typeof(T));

            // initializers
            var bindings = columns.Select(o => o.Trim())
                .Select(o =>
                {
                    // property "Field1"
                    var mi = typeof(T).GetProperty(o);

                    // original value "o.Field1"
                    var xOriginal = Expression.Property(xParameter, mi);

                    // set value "Field1 = o.Field1"
                    return Expression.Bind(mi, xOriginal);
                });

            // initializes "new Data { Field = o.Field1, Field2 = o.Field2 }"
            var xInit = Expression.MemberInit(xNew, bindings);

            // expression "o => new data { Field = o.Field1, Field2 = o.Field2 }"
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(xInit, xParameter);

            // compile to Func<Data, Data>
            return lambda.Compile();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic objects:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/walkthrough-creating-and-using-dynamic-objects

But you really, really should reconsider. Why do you want to do this? Why not have properties with `null` values?

Comment: I am setting these results to a DataGrid and later want to be able to export said DataGrid to a csv and it would be easier if the DataGrid objects, which display just the fields I want but still contain the null values, only had those fields I want included.

Comment: Move the effort you're trying to spend on making an object with only the columns you want over to configuring the grid to just show the columns you want.